# Serial object as function parameter in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a class called Client. The constructor of that class is defined as

```
Client(HardwareSerial * serial);
```

I also have a private field `HardwareSerial * serial` in my class. In the constructor I assign `this->serial = serial`. The class is initiated with `Client * client = new Client(&Serial2);`.

Everything is fine until I call `this->serial->begin(baud)` in the constructor. Arduino gets stuck after this point. What is happening?

Class definition

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

class Client {
  private:
    HardwareSerial * serial;

  public:
    Client(HardwareSerial * serial);
};
```

Class implementation

```
#include "Client.h"

Client::Client(HardwareSerial * serial) {
  this->serial = serial;
  this->serial->begin(115200);
}
```

And instantiation

```
Client * client = new Client(&Serial2);
```

Passing a Stream object to the class instead (changing the variable types, of course) and calling begin in the Arduino setup function works but this is not optimal. This way the class won't handle the calling of the begin function.

Comment: @RickAstley I added the relevant code snippets.

Comment: @RickAstley What do you mean?

Comment: @RickAstley It's defined by Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor gets called before the serial interface is initialized.

You need to have a `begin` method that is then called inside `setup()`.

Client.h

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

class Client {
  private:
    HardwareSerial * serial;

  public:
    Client(HardwareSerial * serial);
    void begin();
};
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"

Client::Client(HardwareSerial * serial) {
  this->serial = serial;
}

void Client::begin() {
  this->serial->begin(115200);
}
```

Your program:

```
#include "Client.h"

Client * client = new Client(&Serial2);

void setup() {
  client->begin();
}
```